# What type of bolt has a shoulder portion above and unthreaded region below threads?

Tags: bolts

I have a couple Rex folding lounge chairs:

[image]

However, during my move one of the bolts connecting the base to the side came loose and was lost. I took out the one from the other side and I've never seen something like it and I'm not sure where to find a replacement. It has larger diameter shoulder portion above the threads and a narrow. unthreaded region below the threads. It's got a low profile slotted pan head. The narrower lower unthreaded region runs up and down in a groove in the leg when the chair folds/unfolds.

Here is a picture of the bolt:

[image]

What is this called? Anyone know where to order one?

Comment: That looks like a pretty special unit to me I doubt you'll find one at home depot. It doesn't look like anything a skilled machinist couldn't fashion out of a carriage bolt on a lathe though, might be worth the phone call?

Comment: @paperstreet You could probably fake one up using a drill-press, a bit of plastic tubing for the chuck to grip onto and a hand file. Cordless drill might even suffice if you clamped it down somehow.

Comment: If you bought it new, for what you paid for it, they should send you a replacement bolt.

Comment: The term is `pivot bolt`, but this is a specialized type that is custom made for this application.

Comment: I would of suggested drilling it out to use a standard bolt but looking up Rex chairs after DA01's comment, they had *better* send you one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not going to find this on a shelf, you may get one from the manufacturer of the chair, if you talk nice and beg. Otherwise the chance is slim.

I would get a pan or philister head machine screw with the threaded portion about 1" longer than the screw pictured is over all. Chuck 3/4" of the threaded end in a drill and crank it down. Turn on the drill, keep it steady and run a file to grind off the threads exposed beyond the drill chuck to smooth the shank like the one in the picture. Since the screw is longer than needed and the drill damaged the end of the threads to hold it while it was spinning, cut it off and soften the corners like the original.

The drawing I referred to earlier

[image]

Comment: You could suggest that if the bolt that the OP goes to buy has threads farther up to the head than the original it may be a good idea to fill the extra part of the threads with epoxy to smooth the upper shank of the bolt so it does not cut the wood in the bolt hinge hole. I would suggest gobbing on plenty of the epoxy, such as JB Weld brand, and then after it is fully set up you can use the drill idea to spin the bolt and file off the excess epoxy to get a nice smooth round upper shank.

Comment: This will get the beginning of the thread between the bolt head and the smoothed part slightly damaged. To prevent that you drive a nut onto the thread and once grinding is complete you drive the nut away and it kind of restores the thread - see this http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/12465/807 for more details.

Comment: Sharptooth, please reread the part about the bolt being 1" longer than needed, and chucking that into the drill only 3/4" That gives a 1/4" play to cut it off with no damage.

Comment: @Jack: I've read that carefully. I'm talking about the thread part that is closer to the head, not the part which will be cut off. Both are damaged when you grind and the former needs to be restored, otherwise how will you use the bolt?

Comment: I will make a drawing to illustrate in a while. The drill chuck will not touch any other part of the threaded section.

Comment: @Jack: The chuck will not, but the file will. No matter how carefully you grind the threading will be damaged slightly and will need restoration.

Comment: If you wish to call the burs created by the file as damage, so be it. I have used files to create the leading thread for nuts to start on. Just as you suggested, a nut can be placed on the screw first before it is chucked into the drill. That way of removing it will clear the bur/damage. IMHO, the portion of shank that has been cleared of threads will act as a guide to allow the nut to go right on. Cross-threading will not be the issue here, which is usually the concern when grinding or cutting something with threads.